# C++ multiple inheritance static function call ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I have the case where I am deriving a class from two different base classes both having a static function with the same name.

To resolve this ambiguity, I tried to use the scope operator - just as I would do for a member function. However This does not compile. **Why? Wrong syntax?**

I want to call the static function via the derived typename and not directly via base class name. Actually I would like prefer to prevent this case, but I have no idea how to do so.

The error (commented out) in the code below also occurs, when I leave the templates away:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class TDerived>
class StaticBaseA
{
public:
    static void announce()
    {
        std::cout << "do something" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class TDerived>
class StaticBaseB
{
public:
    static void announce()
    {
        std::cout << "do something else" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived :
      public StaticBaseA<Derived>
    , public StaticBaseB<Derived>
{
    using StaticBaseA<Derived>::announce;
};

class NonDerived {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived::announce();
    // What I want:
    //Derived::StaticBaseB<Derived>::announce(); Error: "Undefined symbol 'StaticBaseB'

    // What works, but what I don't want ...
    StaticBaseB<Derived>::announce();

    // ... because I would like to prevent this (however this is done):
    StaticBaseB<NonDerived>::announce();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are looking for some kind of template specialisation.

The line that says "What I want" makes no real sense. What do you want it to call?

Comment: Well, if I had a member function the scope operator would be: obj.StaticBaseB<Derived>::announce() - i want that but without the object.

Comment: Does my answer below work (change public to protected in the base-class templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making "announce" `protected` in `StaticBaseA` and `StaticBaseB` might be part-way to doing what you want.

You then could not call `StaticBaseB<NonDerived>::announce` from main as it would be inaccessible. You could call it from a class derived from StaticBaseB.

In other words:

```
template<class TDerived>
class StaticBaseA
{
protected:
   static void announce()
   {
       std::cout << "do something" << std::endl;
   }
};

template<class TDerived>
class StaticBaseB
{
protected:
   static void announce()
   {
       std::cout << "do something else" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In Derived you have to promote "announce" to public.

```
class Derived : public StaticA<Derived>, public StaticB<Derived >
{
  public:
     using StaticA<Derived>::announce;
};

int main()
{
     Derived::announce(); // legal and calls StaticBaseA::announce
     NotDerived::announce(); // no such function
     StaticBaseA< Derived >::announce(); // not accessible
     StaticBaseB< Derived >::announce(); // also not accessible
     StaticBaseA< NotDerived >::announce(); // not accessible
     StaticBaseB< NotDerived >::announce(); // also not accessible
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I can't access Derived::announce() anymore.

Comment: To have 'announce()' of the base class protected and declare the 'using' directive 'public' in the derived class does not work:  'StaticBaseA<Derived>::announce()' is not accessible in function main. From what I understand, this promotion is not possible.

Comment: You are not supposed to call 'StaticBaseA<Derived>::announce in main, you call Derived::announce() which forwards to StaticBaseA

And StaticBaseB<Derived>::announce is not accessible at all

Comment: Interesting: The promotion works with some compilers (clang++ 3.1, g++ 4.7.1) and some not (bcc32 5.82, g++ egcs-2.91.57 (cygwin), )

Comment: Interesting: The promotion works with some compilers (clang++ 3.1, g++ 4.7.1, vc10, but also with g++ -std=c++98). However, some older compilers can not compile this (bcc32 5.82, g++ egcs-2.91.57 (cygwin)) - so the whole thing is just a compiler bug already fixed. Thanks, CashCow!